# LDAP client cannot login on GDM

Tags: login, 19.04, gdm, ldap

I am setting up my Ubuntu 19.04 desktop to work with an openldap server.
I cannot login using GDM.

I have added nscd and I have changed my set-up as follows:

```
common-account:account  [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so 
common-auth:auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so use_first_pass

common-password:password    [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die] pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
common-session:session  optional    pam_ldap.so 
               session  optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=077
common-session-noninteractive:session   optional            pam_ldap.so

nsswitch.conf:passwd:         files systemd ldap
              group:          files systemd ldap
              shadow:         files ldap
```

In a terminal (su - user) I can login without issues, but using GDM, my password is accepted, it appears to log me in, but then I go back to the login screen. 
/var/log/auth.log says:

```
Aug  2 17:02:24 silver-linux gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Aug  2 17:02:24 silver-linux systemd-logind[1034]: New session c4 of user gdm.
Aug  2 17:02:24 silver-linux systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Aug  2 17:02:26 silver-linux polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c4 (system bus name :1.264 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Aug  2 17:02:40 silver-linux gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=dries
Aug  2 17:02:40 silver-linux gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Aug  2 17:02:40 silver-linux gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user dries by (uid=0)
Aug  2 17:02:40 silver-linux systemd-logind[1034]: New session 15 of user dries.
Aug  2 17:02:40 silver-linux systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user dries by (uid=0)
Aug  2 17:02:41 silver-linux dbus-daemon[1056]: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
Aug  2 17:02:41 silver-linux dbus-daemon[1056]: nss_ldap: reconnected to LDAP server ldap://fileserver.familie-dokter.lan after 1 attempt
Aug  2 17:02:43 silver-linux gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user dries
Aug  2 17:02:43 silver-linux systemd-logind[1034]: Session 15 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Aug  2 17:02:49 silver-linux gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Aug  2 17:03:00 silver-linux systemd-logind[1034]: Session c4 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Aug  2 17:03:00 silver-linux polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c4 (system bus name :1.264, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Aug  2 17:03:00 silver-linux systemd-logind[1034]: Removed session c4.
```

I looked at what is described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication) but:

```
lokaal@silver-linux:~$ sudo apt-get install ldap-auth-client nscd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ldap-auth-client is already the newest version (0.5.4).
nscd is already the newest version (2.29-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
lokaal@silver-linux:~$ sudo auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap
sudo: auth-client-config: command not found
```

I am at ropes end here.......

Comment: I also encounter the problem `auth-client-config` command not found.

Comment: Did you read https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM ?

Answer (score 0):

How I configure client LDAP on Debian and Ubuntu (probably Mint, etc. too).  This assumes you have a working LDAP server with at least one user and group.

```
sudo apt install etckeeper # Well you should do that first but it's optional.
```

The package `libpam-ldapd` is newer and better than `libpam-ldap` (without the "d" on the end):

```
sudo apt install libpam-ldapd
```

Fill out the "LDAP server URI:" field. If the server is on the same machine as the client, you can use the default `ldapi:///`.

Fill out the "LDAP server search base:". This is usually the [`dc=` domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756688/what-are-cn-ou-dc-in-an-ldap-search) components.

Select at least the passwd, group and shadow check boxes.  You can choose to put more types in your client configuration if you like.

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` is automatically configured for you.

PAM is automatically configured for you.

Set `binddn` and `bindpw` in `/etc/nslcd.conf` to the DN and password of an account that can bind.

Set `rootpwmoddn` in `/etc/nslcd.conf` to the admin account DN. No admin password is needed in `/etc/nslcd.conf` if you choose a non-admin account for `binddn`.

Run `sudo pam-auth-update`. Then check the check box for "Create home directory on login" (leave the other check boxes as-is).

Reboot (or maybe just restart nscd and nslcd).

There may be a short delay before LDAP responds.

```
mc@openldap:~$ sudo systemctl restart nscd
mc@openldap:~$ sudo systemctl restart nslcd
mc@openldap:~$ id puppy
id: ‘puppy’: no such user
mc@openldap:~$ id puppy
id: ‘puppy’: no such user
mc@openldap:~$ id puppy
id: ‘puppy’: no such user
mc@openldap:~$ id puppy
id: ‘puppy’: no such user
mc@openldap:~$ id puppy
uid=10000(puppy) gid=10000(puppies) groups=10000(puppies)

$ sudo passwd puppy
LDAP administrator password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully

mc@openldap:~$ su - puppy
Password: 
puppy@openldap:~$
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM

Comment: Have you tested any of this on Ubuntu? If not, I am afraid it is off topic, and will be deleted.

Comment: I just tested it on an Ubuntu VM.  It seemed slightly more automatic than on Debian in that it fetched the DNS SRV records for my LDAP server and filled in some of the form based on that.